# R icon in the header in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I am working on my report in Overleaf.com. I don't know how, but this mint green R icon at the top (on the left side of Review ) has appeared. 
[image]
How can I remove it? When I hover mouse over it, it displays an user name unknown to me. Kindly tell me what can be done? I am worried that it my report might be copied or accessed by some other user.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! Not strictly a TeX question... But click on "Share" to the right and see who else has access to your document. And turn off link sharing if it is enabled, if you want no one else to be able to access this document.

Answer (score 1):

(This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team.)

If you see someone you do not know accessing your project, please get in touch with the team at support@overleaf.com and (if it's OK for us to see what you are working on) include the project ID (link) in your request. We will check what's going on.

Second thing you can do is to check the list of collaborators under the Share button. If you have link-sharing on, you can also switch it off temporarily as this could be a sign that either you or someone you shared the project with has leaked the token access link.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I switched off link sharing and I am no longer seeing the icon. Once again, thank you for the prompt response.